# I get an error message in Schema that it is not registered. See the description below

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

So. I'm attempting to use mongoDB with an expressjs project using mongoose, and I get this error

C:\Users\Sanjay\Desktop\BasicNodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:434
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Blog".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)

Please see the source code below, and let me know what changes needs to be done

this is the schema code....   blog.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let blogSchema = new Schema(
    {
        blogId: {
            type: String,
            unique: true
        },
        title: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        description: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        bodyHtml: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        views: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        isPublished: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        author: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        },
        tags: [],
        created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        lastModified: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    };
); 

mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema)
```

this is main js file code... index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const appConfig = require('./config/appConfig');
const fs = require('fs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();


let modelsPath = './models';
fs.readdirSync(modelsPath).forEach(function (file){
    if(~file.indexOf('.js')) {
        require(modelsPath+'/'+file);
    };
});

app.listen(appConfig.port, () => {
    console.log('example app listening on port 3000');
    let db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/blogAppDB');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try below one :

**MODEL :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let blogSchema = new Schema(
   /*your schema fields*/
    };
); 

module.exports = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema) // here we export this schema to use in controller part
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
var Blog = require('../models/blog.js');
```

now you can use Blog to make DB operation

Comment: the same error or some others error, Please let me know??